# Highlighted text not visible on Emacs manuals not visible on HPC

Tags: fonts, highlighting

I installed GNU Emacs on a headless High-Performance-Cluster (Ubuntu 18.04). My emacs configuration is: [init.el](https://gist.github.com/RAraghavarora/835dd9ac15ffcef9120efcf3cf24f685).
I installed emacs using conda: `conda install -c conda-forge emacs`

The same configuration works perfectly on my local Windows system. But when I open this on the cluster, the highlighted text in EMACS manuals is not visible.
[image: emacs screenshot]
In the screenshot you can see white markers making the text unreadable. Similarly, the icons for mode-line are also not available.

Is this some common setting which needs to be changed? Or are fonts unavailable on the cluster which causes this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What terminal are you using to connect to your headless cluster?

Comment: @g-gundam I am using Windows Powershell. I tried it on cygwin, and it's the same